# Regular Expression: replace string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want a regular expression to match a string like this **"(192)"**

the string starts with **"("** and ends with **")"** and numbers from **0 to 9** go between the parentheses.

I've tried this function before but it does not work:

```
function remove_garbage_numbers(str) {
    var find = '^\([0-9]\)$';
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

    return str.replace(re, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass this to `RegExp` constructor. And you don't need to have a `g` modifier when anchors are used. And aso when anchors are used, it's safe to use `m` multiline modifier.

```
var find = /^\([0-9]+\)$/m;
```

ie,

```
function remove_garbage_numbers(str) {
    var re = /^\([0-9]+\)$/m;
    return str.replace(re, '');
}
```

**OR**

```
var re = new RegExp("^\\([0-9]+\\)$", 'm');
```

ie,

```
function remove_garbage_numbers(str) {

    var re = new RegExp("^\\([0-9]+\\)$", 'm');

    return str.replace(re, '');
}
```

**Update**

```
> "Main (191)|Health & Beauty (6)|Vision Care (8)".replace(/\(\d+\)/g, "")
'Main |Health & Beauty |Vision Care '
```

Comment: Well you would also need to alter the `re` line with this solution.

Comment: Could this be further simplified to `str.replace(/^\([0-9]\)$/g, '')`?

Comment: yep, but you need to put `+` after the char class and you don't even need a g modifier.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work

I have the string "Main (191)|Health & Beauty (6)|Vision Care (8)"
and I need it after replacing to be "Main|Health & Beauty|Vision Care"